# How to ensure focused item in HTML form in a WebView in a UWP app isn't obscured by keyboard

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-10, win-universal-app, uwp

We have a web based form that is displayed in a `WebView` in a UWP app. When data is entered into the form we haven't found a way to ensure that the input field with focus is in the visible area when the software keyboard is displayed so the input field with focus remains visible.

There seems to be some inconsistency in the built in behaviour as sometimes when setting focus on an input field (by tapping it) it will be scrolled into a visible position. Other times it remains hidden behind the keyboard.

In a XAML based UI this is easy to manage by adjusting the layout based on the `Showing` and `Hiding` events of `InputPane`.

We can do the same with content in a WebView to allow the control to be resized and ensure that it is possible to reach all content when scrolled but this doesn't ensure that the field with focus is not obscured when the keyboard is displayed.

Given this scenario is there a way to ensure that the focused control is visible when the keyboard is displayed?

Comment: Great question. I wish it had an answer :(